# How to order by ascending in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, linq

I want to sort by Module Code. I tried adding `OrderBy(m => m.code)` but the error says 'does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy'...'.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Module>> GetAllModules()
{
    return await context.Modules
        .Include(m => m.Lecturers)
            .ThenInclude(ml => ml.Lecturer)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

Module class:

```
public class Module
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ModuleLecturer> Lecturers { get; set; }
        
    public Module()
    {
        Lecturers = new Collection<ModuleLecturer>();
    }
}
```

ModuleLecturer class:

```
public class ModuleLecturer
{
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public int LecturerId { get; set; }
    public Module Module { get; set; }
    public Lecturer Lecturer { get; set; }
}
```

Lecturer class:

```
public class Lecturer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What did you add `OrderBy(m => m.code)` to?

Comment: using System.Linq;

Comment: @dexiang Thanks. Turns out I forgot to include System.Linq.